# How to Manually Start React Native Debugger on Linux - Ubuntu

Tags: react-native, ubuntu, installation, react-native-debugger

I want to enable react -native-debugger on react native development environment. so i followed 
https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger

and downloaded the rn-debugger-linux-x64.zip

then i unzip the file.

what i want know is after that how i manually start the react-native-debugger?

Comment: You should download .deb file from the Github repository releases section.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Check out the Getting Started section of their repo;
`https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md`

Comment: I just want to know how to install and run it on linux os. Ubuntu 19.04

Answer (score 20):

You just have to 
- download .deb file

https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/releases

- double clic to **react-native-debugger_0.10.5_amd64.deb**
- install the app and use this like all other app in your computer

Comment: Right-clicking did not work instead it opened in Archive Manager. I used the terminal:
```sudo dpkg -i react-native-debugger_0.13.0_amd64.deb```

Answer (score 7):

You have 2 main options: the binary files and the deb file.

**If you go for the binary files:**

1. Download the file `rn-debugger-linux-x64.zip`
2. Unpack/extract the content of the file
3. Navigate to where you extracted the package and execute it with `/.` (dot slash) as `./react-native-debugger`
4. You can also add an alias for it in your `.bashrc/.bash_profile` (or
   .zshrc if you're using zsh), e.g.

   alias rn-debug="~/react-native-debugger/react-native-debugger"

**If you go for the deb file**: Here you have 3 options:

1. double click: Super simple but you may have the well known dependency error.
2. gdebi: It is a lightweight GUI application with the sole purpose of installing deb packages. It identifies the dependencies and tries to install these along with the .deb files.
3. dpkg/apt line command: `sudo apt install path_to_deb_file`

For me **gdebi** is the best option among all. So with gdebi just download the deb file, open gdebi and indicate to it the path to your file. Piece of cake!

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

When you unzip all the files, you will find executable inside. In Ubuntu you run it in terminal from your folder with:

```
./react-native-debugger
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/issues/116#issuecomment-475866514

to install on Ubuntu you will need to:

1. download the latest rn-debugger-linux-x64.zip from
2. unzip it and move the folder to /opt

   cd ~/Downloads
   sudo unzip rn-debugger-linux-x64.zip -d /opt/ReactNativeDebugger
3. preferably rename the executable

   cd /opt/ReactNativeDebugger
   sudo mv 'React Native Debugger' rndebugger
4. Add the folder which includes the React Native Debugger renamed executable to your path

   vim ~/.bash_profile
   export PATH="$PATH:/opt/ReactNativeDebugger"
5. Download the icon from the repository and place it in your /opt/ReactNativeDebugger folder

   sudo mv ~/Downloads/logo.png /opt/ReactNativeDebugger/logo.png
6. Create a desktop entry, so that you can pin react native debugger to your dock

   vim ~/.local/share/applications/rndebugger.desktop

Include and edit the entry and save the file.
It is important that you replace Exec and Icon with the absolute path to the executable and logo files

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=0.9.7
Type=Application
Name=ReactNativeDebugger
Exec=/opt/ReactNativeDebugger/rndebugger
Icon=/opt/ReactNativeDebugger/logo.png
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=rndebugger
```

Answer (score 1):

Download. deb files from https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/releases

To install a . deb file, simply Right click on the . ...

Alternatively, you can also install a .deb file by opening a terminal and typing: sudo dpkg -i package_file.deb.

To uninstall a .deb file, remove it using Adept, or type: sudo apt-get remove package_name.